# Split string when first occurence of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, and I need to split the text between string and numbers:

Ex.:

```
text = "MARIA APARECIDA 99223-2000 / 98450-8026"
```

OUTPUT:

```
parte_1 = MARIA APARECIDA

parte_2 = 99223-2000 / 98450-8026
```

Comment: What have you written to try and accomplish this, and how does it come up short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting on the first occurrence of `[ ](?=\d)`:

```
text = "MARIA APARECIDA 99223-2000 / 98450-8026"
parts = re.split(r' (?=\d)', text, 1)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['MARIA APARECIDA', '99223-2000 / 98450-8026']
```

Note that the regex pattern used splits and consumes a single space, but does *not* consume the digit that follows (lookaheads do not advance the position in the input).